# how merge sort work in panda of python to sort the excel file by column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort excel file using python merge sort algorithm. So, is there any method to apply the merge sort algorithm in pandas with something like:

`sort_values(by='columnname',  ascending=False, kind="mergesort")`?

I have tried:

```
def merge_sort(list1, left_index, right_index):  
    if left_index >= right_index:  
        return  
    
middle = (left_index + right_index)//2  
merge_sort(list1, left_index, middle)  
merge_sort(list1, middle + 1, right_index)  
merge(list1, left_index, right_index, middle)  
      
      
# Defining a function for merge the list  
def merge(list1, left_index, right_index, middle):  
      
    # Creating subparts of a lists  
    left_sublist = list1[left_index:middle + 1]  
    right_sublist = list1[middle+1:right_index+1]  
      
    # Initial values for variables that we use to keep  
    # track of where we are in each list1  
    left_sublist_index = 0  
    right_sublist_index = 0  
    sorted_index = left_index  
      
    # traverse both copies until we get run out one element  
    while left_sublist_index < len(left_sublist) and right_sublist_index < len(right_sublist):  
  
        # If our left_sublist has the smaller element, put it in the sorted  
        # part and then move forward in left_sublist (by increasing the pointer)  
        if left_sublist[left_sublist_index] <= right_sublist[right_sublist_index]:  
            list1[sorted_index] = left_sublist[left_sublist_index]  
            left_sublist_index = left_sublist_index + 1  
        # Otherwise add it into the right sublist  
        else:  
            list1[sorted_index] = right_sublist[right_sublist_index]  
            right_sublist_index = right_sublist_index + 1  
  
    # move forward in the sorted part  
    sorted_index = sorted_index + 1  
  
    # we will go through the remaining elements and add them  
    while left_sublist_index < len(left_sublist):  
        list1[sorted_index] = left_sublist[left_sublist_index]  
        left_sublist_index = left_sublist_index + 1  
        sorted_index = sorted_index + 1  
  
    while right_sublist_index < len(right_sublist):  
        list1[sorted_index] = right_sublist[right_sublist_index]  
        right_sublist_index = right_sublist_index + 1  
        sorted_index = sorted_index + 1 

#drive the code
df=pd.read_excel('framelist.xlsx') 
temp = df["CGPA"]  # CGPA is the column of the excel file to be sorted
merge_sort(temp, 0, len(temp) -1)
```

But it doesn't generate a sorted list.
please help me